# Windows 8 Dwm/Aero - No Side Margins

Tags: .net, windows-8, aero, margins, dwm

I have a .NET 2.0 app that calls DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea on some forms to create glass-like effect on certain sides as defined by the MARGINS structure. It works as expected on Windows Vista and Windows 7. However, on Windows 8 (and I tried both - the Developer Preview and the Consumer Preview released last week) - only the top and bottom margins get rendered properly. The left and Right margins are ignored as if they were set to 0. Does anyone have any idea why? Is this something temporary and will be fixed? Have they changed the structure/layout of the MARGINS structure?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, obviously it sounds like an issue within Windows 8. I would ask on MSDN forums like http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowsuidevelopment/threads or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowscompatibility/threads. There is likely some engineer on there with a commitment to answer all questions within a few days at most. Maybe someone has a workaround to your issue or maybe it is a bug someone needs to tell them about...

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will try that. It kind of seems surprising to me that no one has noticed it, or I am just one of those rare people who happen to use side margins with Aero...

Comment: I'm sure there are tons of applications that do it, but it is possible they were not tested on Windows 8 yet or for some other reason do not suffer from this problem there. Anyways - don't let the Windows team focus too much on Metro and leave the desktop crippled!

Comment: I have posted this on MSDN forums, and MSFT employee replied that they are investigating the issue. At least they confirmed that it is an existing issue and are aware of it...